# Загрузка музыки со стрима на Youtube

Tags: python, youtube

Как с помощью python воспроизводить постоянно только аудио с
[этого стрима](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ)?

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Взять youtube-dl?

Comment: там так можно что-ли?

Comment: прикол в том, что мне нужно динамично загружать музыку

Comment: @CyberRik А какая разница? Динамично, не динамично. Все равно только так с YouTube можно загружать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для прослушивания музыки со стрима в фоне можно воспользоваться `vlc` плеером.
Он есть как на `Linux`, так и на `Windows`, что довольно удобно.

***Пример:***

```py
import youtube_dl
import vlc
from time import sleep


VIDEO_URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ'

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL()
video = ydl.extract_info(
    VIDEO_URL,
    download=False,
)
url = video['url']

instance = vlc.Instance('--no-video')
player = instance.media_player_new()
media = instance.media_new(url)
player.set_media(media)

player.play()

while True:
    pass
```

Получаем `URL` стрима с помощью `youtube_dl` и передаём его плееру с параметром `--no-video`.

Обратите внимание, что должен быть установлен сам `VLC` плеер.

Comment: у меня выходит ошибка((

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kmRHtvak

Comment: @CyberRik У Вас модуль не находит `vlc` плеер. Убедитесь, что установили его. Такая же проблема возникает, если пытаться использовать виртуальное окружение. Должны помочь переменные среды, но я не до конца в этом разобрался. В общем, это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: 1. я установил python-vlc  с помощью pip
2.не использую виртуальное окружение

Comment: @CyberRik Нужен не только модуль, но и [сам `vlc` плеер](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.ru.html). Модуль - это привязка, которая предоставляет удобное `API`.

Comment: ааа, спасибо, ща поставлю

Comment: А теперь пишет то же самое, но последняя строка сменилась на
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32

Comment: @CyberRik По ссылке выше не жмите сразу скачать, а нажмите на стрелочку и выберите `Windows` (**не** `Windows 64bit`, она скачивается по умолчанию). Ох уж эти зависимости... :)

Comment: Keyerror на строке url=video['url'], а  не знаю, какой url брать((

Comment: Прошу прощения, обновил yotube-dl и все заработало, спасибо))

Comment: И можно ли отключить вывод youtube-dl и vlc в консоль?)

Comment: И лучше вместо while true pass писать input(), т.к он грузит проц))

Answer (score 1):

Код ниже скачивает стрим с текущего момента определённый промежуток времени.
После чего конвертирует в `mp3` с наилучшим качеством.

***Код:***

```py
import youtube_dl
import subprocess


VIDEO_URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ'
TIME = '00:00:10.00'  # 10 секунд

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL()
video = ydl.extract_info(
    VIDEO_URL,
    download=False,
)

url = video['url']

subprocess.call(f'ffmpeg -i "{url}" -ss 00:00:00.00 -t {TIME} -vn -sn -b:a 320K music.mp3', shell=True)
```

Для получение `URL` я использую `youtube_dl`, а для скачивания и преобразования - `ffmpeg`.

Если Вы используете `Windows`, то убедитесь, что в папке с программой находится содержимое папки `ffmpeg\bin`. Кстати, для `Windows` `ffmpeg` можно скачать [тут](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: ну вот смотри, как мне непрерывно проигрывать этот стрим(знаю, изначально неверно задал вопрос)

Comment: не знаете случайно?

Comment: и да, ваш код, к сожалению, у меня не работает

Comment: А зачем конвертировать-то, если можно сохранить оригинальный аудиопоток?

Comment: @andreymal А Вы уверены, что есть оригинальный аудиопоток? Я просмотрел информацию о доступных форматах (`ydl.extract_info()['formats']`) и единственная оптимизация, которая у меня получилась, - это скачивание видео в 144p. Подскажите, пожалуйста, очень интересно действительно ли можно скачать только аудио.

Comment: @nomnoms12 вы ж сами `{url}` написали, там и есть оригинальный аудиопоток

Comment: @andreymal Действительно, туплю я :) Необязательно конвертировать.

Comment: @nomnoms12 с параметрами по умолчанию ffmpeg всё равно выполняет конвертирование (в каком-нибудь ужасном качестве по умолчанию)

Comment: А ещё у меня этот пример выдаёт ошибку `KeyError: 'url'`

Comment: @CyberRik Скорее всего проблема в том, что у вас нет библиотеки `youtube_dl`. Не говорите сразу "у меня не работает", разберитесь сначала где не работает, и почему.

Comment: У меня тоже KeyError выходит